# I am trying extract data from website using request and bs4 python module. when i try to access this code, got below error message to json

Tags: python, json, web, python-requests, decoder

```
capcha2 = requests.post(url=url1,headers=headers3,data=payload1)
print(capcha2)
cap = json.loads(capcha2.text)
captcha_status = cap['required']
print(captcha_status)
```

when i try to load value to json, got below error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Madeena\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\pythonProject2\ahamed3.py", line 39, in <module>
    cap = json.loads(capcha2.text)
  File "C:\Users\Madeena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Madeena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Madeena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

i tried `capcha2 = requests.post(url=url1,headers=headers3,data=payload1).json()`
got same error message

Comment: Did you parse the data with bs4?

Comment: No. i tried json() response = requests.get(url, params=params)
    print(response.json()) - it gives output without error. but it triggered when i use post method

Answer (score 1):

Method text for response can return json or html. In your case, capture2.text most likely returns html and because of this, json.loads() gives an error that it cannot parse this string in json. Use capture2.json() in the same way as after the get request.